# Python and Web Scraping - CSV Output Issues

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am currently trying to run a Python script to pull some data from a Yahoo Fantasy Football Website. I have been able to successfully scrape data, but am running into an issue with the CSV output. All of the data is being put into one column instead of multiple different columns. Below is my code I am using:

```
import re, time, csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Variables
League_ID = 1459285
Week_Number = 1
Start_Week = 1
End_Week = 13
Team_Name = "Test"
Outfile = 'Team_Stats.csv'
Fields = ['Player Name', 'Player Points', 'Player Team', 'Week']


with open('Team_Stats.csv','w') as Team_Stats:
        f = csv.writer(Team_Stats, Fields, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        f.writerow(Fields)


    for Week_Number in range(Start_Week, End_Week + 1):
            url = requests.get("https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/" + str(League_ID) + "/2/team?&week=" + str(Week_Number))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
            #print("Player Stats for " + Team_Name + " for Week " + str(Week_Number))

            player_name=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'ysf-player-name'})
            player_points=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pps Fw-b has-stat-note '})

            for player_name in player_name:
                    player_name = player_name.contents[0]
                    #print(div.text)
                    f.writerow(player_name)

            for player_points in player_points:
                    #print(div.text)
                    Week_Number += 1
                    f.writerow(player_points)

    Team_Stats.flush()
    Team_Stats.close()
    print("Process Complete")
```

I also want to leave some room in the code to add more 'For loops' since I have other pieces of data I am looking to collect.

If anyone can suggest a better way to structure my code, please feel free to help!!

**This is a sample output of what I get in my csv file**

[image: screen shot]

Thanks

Comment: You already appear to know that `writerow` takes a list as an argument. You have 2 `for` loops _in series_ writing to the file. Collect the results in a nested list and _then_ write for a single row.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, time, csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Variables
League_ID = 1459285
Week_Number = 1
Start_Week = 1
End_Week = 13
Team_Name = "Test"
Outfile = 'Team_Stats.csv'
Fields = ['Player Name', 'Player Points', 'Player Team', 'Week']


with open('Team_Stats.csv','w') as Team_Stats:
    f = csv.writer(Team_Stats, Fields, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    f.writerow(Fields)


    for Week_Number in range(Start_Week, End_Week + 1):
        row = []
        url = requests.get("https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/" + str(League_ID) + "/2/team?&week=" + str(Week_Number))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
            #print("Player Stats for " + Team_Name + " for Week " + str(Week_Number))

        player_name=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'Nowrap name F-link'})
        player_points=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pps Fw-b has-stat-note '})

        for pn, pp in zip(player_name, player_points):
                player_name = pn.contents[0]
                player_points = pp.contents[0]
                f.writerow([player_name, player_points])

    Team_Stats.flush()
    Team_Stats.close()
    print("Process Complete")
```

1) Wrong classes for scraping player_name

2) I use `zip()` to iterate over two lists at once, to construct a row with name and points

Comment: I tried this solution, but still does not give me the correct output. If you can see the picture I posted, I am just looking to move the numbers to the column to the right, and so on so forth...

Comment: I've tested this code and find out that it works totally wrong.
You have to, at least, figure out correct scraping to construct correct rows as a lists. There is problem not in CSV output, there's a problem with input(scraped data)